# set images to fit in screen in webbrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

i am working on windows mobile phone 7, i have a html form data that i displayed in webbrowser control using `NavigateToString` . on orientation change to avoid zoomed-in the content i have use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` and it worked for me. 
but now the problem is the images that comes from the link that is in html form data; they dont fit into the screen and i get horizontal scroll to view it. how can i set images to fit in screen accordingly on both orientations.

in Android i did this by

`webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);`

Answer (score 0):

You can go for two solutions
1. With the help of script invoke(java script invoke method) you can hard code the size of the image
2. You download the image with the help of webclient / httpwebrequest and handle the pinch & zoom functionality with in you view. This method would be effective when comparing with the first.

Enjoy coding.

Comment: i dont think its a good approach to hard code the size. because on orientation change (i.e Landscape) i want image to resize, if i hard code it then i wont get different sizes on orientation change

Comment: Then better yo treat this webpage locally. ie first you parse this page and take the image and corresponding contents. and then apply pinch and zoom.